# PHP parse YAML, store in DB for easy value modification, and return to original structure afterwards

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, multidimensional-array, yaml

I require the ability to store, modify and retrieve YAML data *content* in a MySQL database.

**My project (and question) aims:**

- Parse .yml files into a PHP multi-dimensional array
- Store these into a MySQL database
- Allow modification of individual values within the database *primary aim*
- Retrieve the values from the database, parse, and place back into a .yml file

**Step 1 - An Example YAML file**

```
string 'name:
  singular: null
  plural: null
fields:
  price:
    label: Preis
  company_id:
     label: null
     placeholder: null'
```

The important things to note here are that there *could be an unlimited number of nested keys*, and also *keys and values may have the same name / data*.

**Step 2 - Place this into a PHP array**

I'm using [a library called Spyc](http://code.google.com/p/spyc/) to parse the YAML. This works great! It gives me the following:

```
array
  'name' => 
    array
      'singular' => null
      'plural' => null
  'fields' => 
    array
      'price' => 
        array
          'label' => string 'Preis' (length=5)
      'company_id' => 
        array
          'label' => null
          'placeholder' => null
```

My aim next is to store each of these in a MySQL database. So...

**Step 3 - CSV them**

Here I have written my own function, which is basically a long list of `foreach()`s to separate these details into the following array:

```
array
   0 => string 'name||singular||' (length=16)
   1 => string 'name||plural||' (length=14)
   2 => string 'fields||price||label||Preis' (length=27)
   3 => string 'fields||company_id||label||' (length=27)
   4 => string 'fields||company_id||placeholder||' (length=33)
```

**Step 4 - MySQL DB**

Logically, I'm trying to store these strings in a database. I'm not sure of the schema. I'm guessing value will be the `end($array[$key]` in a **value** column, and the **key** column will contain the rest of the elements in the array.

This will effectively allow me to change values within the database before pulling them back out, parsing and returning to the .yml file.

**Step 5 - I'm LOST!**

So I'm not sure what to do now. Currently I'm trying to parse these strings with the following logic:

- The last value `end($array[$key]` is the value, and all previous elements in the array are the parent keys
- Once I've gotten that code working, effectively turning those strings back into an array would be the next priority

There's got to be a better way to do this. My main aim is to be able to update the individual values in the database. My main problem is the fact that the array dimension count is not constant.

**How I can be helped**

Please offer me:

- More appropriate methods of achieving my project aims (see top) if there are any
- The best way to store this data in the database allowing easy modification of values (for example the `null`s you see in Step 1)
- Upon returning this data from the database, a PHP function to return these keys and values **to the exact structure** of the original array (Step 2) so that I can use Spyc to convert this back to YAML and output to the .yml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a key-value store that can be serialized as YAML, you should probably just create that:

```
CREATE TABLE key_values(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT,
  type VARCHAR(255),
  key VARCHAR(255),
  value VARCHAR(255)
)
```

In this case, `id` is how you refer to the root record, `parent_id` is a mechanism for linking in child records, `type` is used to distinguish between an array map and an indexed array. `key` and `value` are used to store the respective values.

With this you should be able to create the appropriate records.

An example from your data might be to create the root node:

```
INSERT INTO key_values VALUES (parent_id, type, key, value)
  VALUES (NULL, 'map', NULL NULL)
```

Then add in the values for the `name` key presuming `id` was 1 for the previous `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO key_values VALUES (parent_id, type, key, value)
  VALUES (1, 'map', 'name' NULL)
```

The process repeats recursively for each value:

```
INSERT INTO key_values VALUES (parent_id, type, key, value)
  VALUES (2, 'string', 'singular' NULL),
         (2, 'string', 'plural' NULL)
```

In any case, you'll need to write a wrapper class for all this or it'll be too complicated to use.

In practice I'm not sure going through all of this trouble is going to be much easier than simply storing the YAML as-is inside a `LONGTEXT` field and calling it a day. Manipulating and re-saving is usually not that expensive. Iterating over a multi-tiered tree structure is.

You'll have to be careful to avoid stomping writes in race conditions for the pure YAML approach, though, but that's nothing that can't be solved using a `revision` column that tracks which version you're saving against. Construct your `UPDATE` so that it won't match:

```
UPDATE yamls SET value='...', revision=93 WHERE id=20 AND revision=92
```

If some other process had updated it already you would see the query failed to run and could handle it accordingly.

Comment: This is interesting! I will try your code later. I was originally looking at Modified Pre-order Tree Traversal : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462 but this seems a good (and much easier, more efficient) method.

Comment: With the code from your answer, I should be able to update the child element giving all the parent keys for it. Is this the correct way to access that value then? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83c3c/5 I can write a PHP function to create this string depending on the value sought and the keys passed in. `func($value,array($key1,$key2));` for example...

Comment: It really depends if you want to access one key or many keys. Specifying `type` in your `WHERE` clause shouldn't be necessary as it's only for informational purposes.

Comment: You're right, the wrapper I've got for this is pretty epic, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!